# AngularFirebase FirebaseListObservable can't get get uid

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a list of Users which I want to display.
Which works, I can display the usernames but not the keys.
{{user.uid}} or {{user.key}} prints out nothing, {{user.username}} all the names.
Any Idea?

My Structure looks like that:

[image]

Component.ts

```
    allUsers: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router) {

      this.allUsers = db.list('/users');
   }
```

Component.html

```
  <ul class="list-group gamer-list">
  <li class="list-group-item agamer" *ngFor="let user of allUsers | async">
    <div class="material-switch">
     <input id="switch{{user.username}}" name="switch{{user.username}}" type="checkbox"/>
     <label for="switch{{user.username}}" class="switch{{user.username}}"></label>
                    </div>
                    {{user.key}} - {{user.username}}
                </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: you need to use `.snapshotChanges()` method to get the id, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509757/stuck-at-deleting-parent-pushed-key-by-value-childkey/47511321#47511321) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291644/angular-firebase-5-objects-keys-not-being-displayed-so-cant-delete/47291970#47291970)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't use  this.allUsers = db.list('/users').snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
      }); -> can't use snapshotChanges with a Type of FirebaseListObservable.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my Problem:

I tried to change my code to:

```
 this.userRef = db.list('/users');
      this.allUsers = this.userRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
          return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() 
      }));
     });
```

At first i had

```
allUsers: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

but it seems like snapshotChanges is not possible with FirebasListObservable & I had to do it this way:

```
  userRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  allUsers: Observable<any[]>;
```

But it still was not possible - there was an error in my Coding Programm with this.allUsers, it said it was of type FirebaseListObservable, but it wasn't.
So I changed my import:
From

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
```

To:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList  } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

Hope this helps all of those who face the same problem!