# Routing using object.$key returns undefined - firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I want to route the link by using `$key` in the firebase. However, after going through all the documentations and forums, the answer that I get is to use `object.$key` to retrieve the value. I use it and it still returns `undefined`.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
        <td>{{ p.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.price }}</td>
        <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.$key]">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

`products$` returns an observable of the `AngularFireList`

```
products$;
constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
  this.products$ = this.productService.getAll().valueChanges();
}
```

This is the Product Service definition.

```
export class ProductService {

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product) {
    return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products');
  }

  get(productId) {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
  }
}
```

I still am unsure what is wrong with this as it returns `/admin/products/undefined`

As all of the reference I read state in using this `object.$key`

Comment: use `snapshotChanges` instead of `valueChanges` to get the key, check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509757/stuck-at-deleting-parent-pushed-key-by-value-childkey/47511321#47511321)

Comment: thank you. changed it and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.$key` is no longer present in AngularFire2 v5. If you need the key use `snapshotChanges()` [see our migration guide for more details](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md).

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
  this.products$ = this.productService.getAll().snapshotChanges();
}
```

Then use the payload in your view:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
        <td>{{ p.payload.val().title }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.payload.val().price }}</td>
        <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.key]">Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Or you could map the snapshot changes into a structure you're more familar with:

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
  this.products$ = this.productService.getAll()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .map(s => ({"$key": s.key, ...s.payload.val()}))
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, I've missed this details on the new version. Changed it and it works.